# Workspace or data source is read only

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, arccatalog, iterator

I am using ModelBuilder in ArcCatalog 10.1 to convert an ASCII files to TIFF and add spatial reference. I have hundreds of files to convert so I'm using the Iterators. After doing 10-20 files successfully I get the following error.

```
Executing (ASCII to Raster): ASCIIToRaster "D:\Users\Documents\#Data\# New Data\LIDAR\todo\nz4626_dsm_1m.asc" "C:\Users\Data\# New Data\Lidar2.gdb\nz4626_dsm_1m" FLOAT
Start Time: Thu Aug 15 14:59:06 2013
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Workspace or data source is read only.
Workspace or data source is read only.
No spatial reference exists.
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression. 
Failed to execute (ASCII to Raster).
Failed at Thu Aug 15 14:59:06 2013 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

After using command prompt to remove read only tag from the source and destination folders and restarting ArcCatalog the process can be run again for a few more files before failing again.

What is causing the folders to become read only and how do I stop it?

Comment: Don't know if this will help but you seem to have a # symbol in you path name. I would attempt your processing with folder names without special characters like #!&() or spaces.

Comment: Aaron, it is not ticked

Comment: Hornbydd, I changed the folder names with no effect

Comment: It sounds like your model has only a few elements so perhaps you can post a picture of it so we can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: This [thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/71818-workspace-suddenly-becomes-read-only) discusses a few possible solutions.

Comment: There are some possible solutions here if someone is still experiencing this problem: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/63440

Comment: Could this potentially be due to another user accessing your data /open mxds elsewhere ?

Comment: If you can, try running the same model and data on a machine with more RAM as a test.  It's a slightly long shot but error messages can become unpredictable when RAM is in short supply.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit late. But if your are running into similar problems this can be useful:

If you are using Dropbox, try stopping its syncing and then quit it. Then close and reopen your ArcMap project. This worked for me.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you twice. This issue was giving me random errors in several of my routines depending on when dropbox began syncing the used files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Agreed! This was a very helpful tip. Thank you for sharing